# How can I set a list of string for an OpenApi header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm adding a language header to the `Swagger-UI` and trying to have it as a `drop-down` list. For some reason, it keeps giving me a cast error.
Here is the relevant code:

```
 public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            var enumList = (_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>)) as IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>)?
                        .Value?.SupportedCultures?.Select(c => new OpenApiString(c.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)).ToList();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "Accept-Language",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header, // "header",
                Description = "Supported languages",
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {   
                    Default = new OpenApiString("en"), 
                    Type = "string"


                    //TODO: Can't get this conversion to work and I don't know why...
                    ,
                    Enum = (IList<IOpenApiAny>)enumList

                },
                Required = false
            }) ;
        }
```

And here is the error I'm getting (at runtime):

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.OpenApiString]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.IOpenApiAny]'.

Without the `enum`, everything works great, and the header shows up on each request in the Swagger UI as a text box with the default.

I spent hours trying to find the answer in the docs, but I couldn't.

Comment: Is in "c =>  new OpenApiString()[...]" a class implementing IOpenAPIAny interface?

Comment: Yes, it is as far as I can tell.It inherits OpenApiPrimitive<string> which is defined as `public abstract class OpenApiPrimitive<T> : IOpenApiPrimitive, IOpenApiAny, IOpenApiElement, IOpenApiExtension`

Comment: Then can you try something like explicit type like 
     IList<IOpenApyAny> enumList instead of var enumList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
var enumList = (_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>)) as IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>)?
                        .Value?.SupportedCultures?.Select(c => OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFor(new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "string" }, c.Name)).ToList();
```